# Why do I have to override virtual method instead of using polymorphism?

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have a class named `Employee`. Now I try to define its `Equals` method, but I want to accept an `Employee` as parameter only.

So I write this code:

```
class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Employee e = new Employee();
            Employee e2 = new Employee();
            Console.WriteLine(Equals(e, e2));
        }

        public static Employee CreateEmployee()
        {
            return new Employee();
        }
    } 

    class Employee
    {
        public int ID;
        public bool Equals (Employee e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Compare!");
            return ID == e.ID;
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work! The console outputs:

```
false
```

Not what I expected:

```
Compare!
true
```

It looks like that I have to write `public override bool Equals (Object)`, but why? Can't C# choose the method to call by the type of parameter(s)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing your code to

```
Console.WriteLine(e.Equals(e2));
```

As you had it it was using [Object.Equals Method (Object, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

> I have a class named Employee. Now I try to define its Equals method, but I want to accept an Employee as parameter only.

Then you're not overriding, you're *overloading*. That means anything which wants to call your code *either* has to do it dynamically based on the execution-time types of the parameters, *or* it has to know about your overload ahead of time and take account of it.

The latter is feasible if you make `Employee` implement `IEquatable<Employee>` (and you should still override `GetHashCode`, and ideally *also* override `Equals(object)` for sanity) - then anything which uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` will end up using your method. That would include `Dictionary<,>` etc.

But basically, anything which *expects* to be able to call `Equals(object)` will get the inherited implementation, because you haven't overridden it. C# simply doesn't perform overload resolution at execution time, unless you're using dynamic typing with the `dynamic` type - which has significant impact in other ways, not least performance.

You have two options, really:

- Use a dynamic language which has different rules
- Follow the rules of C#, where the method signature is chosen at compile-time, but the *implementation* of that method signature is determined as execution time polymorphically

Answer (score 0):

You don't get what you expect because you call different **Equals** methods ))) You call method of class **object**, the parent class for all classes in C#, but You expect that You will call Equals method of Employee class. To call Equals method of Employee class you should use `Employee` instance:

```
Employee e1 = new Employee();
Employee e2 = new Employee();
Console.WriteLine(e1.Equals(e2));
```